# How to update existing rows in Room database?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a DAO class for updating a note if a note already exists for a particular date. If note, the DAO creates a new note. Here's the DAO interface:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
public long insertNote(Note note);

@Update
public int updateNote(Note note);
```

Here's how I read all the data from the Database:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteListViewModel.class);
viewModel.getNoteList().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Note> noteList) {
            Log.d("Note List Items", noteList.toString());
      }
});
```

Now, I don't know to check, compare and update existing rows in the database.

Comment: Um, to update a note, call `updateNote()`. Beyond that, what do you mean by "check, compare and update existing rows"?

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean how will the updateNote() know what notes to update?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Note` `@Entity` class has a primary key. `updateNote()` will update the row based on that primary key.

Comment: The only primary key I have in Note is an auto-generated ID. I want to update the row based on checking dates. The date is split into date, day, month, and year. How should I check those against the ones in the database?

Comment: @waseefakhtar: "The only primary key I have in Note is an auto-generated ID. I want to update the row based on checking dates" -- that is what `@Update` will use. "I want to update the row based on checking dates" -- then create a SQL `UPDATE` statement that expresses what you want, and use that in a `@Query`-annotated method in your `@Dao`. While `@Query` is typically used for `SELECT`, we also use it for any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` that is by a means other than the primary key.

Comment: That would work great. However, now I have @Insert and @Query, the query being `@Query("UPDATE notes SET id = :id, noteTitle = :noteTitle, noteDescription = :noteDescription WHERE date = :date AND month = :month AND year = :year")
    public void updateNote(String noteTitle, String noteDescription, String date, String month, String year);`. How and where would I check if I should run @Insert or @Query? How should I check for the existing data before calling @Insert or @Query?

Comment: @waseefakhtar: There is no scenario in which I can envision that even being a question. In one case, you are creating a new entity. In the other case, you are modifying an unknown number of entities. Those operations are not comparable.